# How to detect if SpriteKit game moves to background(the person exits the app)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am creating a SpriteKit game, and in my game scene I don't want them to be able to close the app and then go back into it later and keep playing where they left off.

After some research I figured out that Notification Center lets the app know when it is moved to the background, but I don't know how to implement that into my game? Is it some sort of override of a function, or something I add into my "didMove to view" function.

Im not sure where to start with this because I am using SpriteKit and I haven't been able to find anything online describing how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Talk to the view controller hosting the game with `SKView`.

Comment: You can use the `SceneDelegate` methods to handle life-cycle events. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure SpriteKit works the same, but if we say about usual swift apps, you can use AppDelegate or SceneDelegate files for this, for example I used AppDelegate for the same task (but I haven't used SceneDelegate at all in my app! I think in your case SceneDelegate will be better)

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let viewControllers = navController.viewControllers
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            if viewController.isKind(of: YourTargetViewController.self) {
                // here put your code to open desired ViewController
            }
        }
    }
```